# What is the correct way to check if CancellationToken was invoked for backgroundservice

Tags: c#, background-service, cancellation-token

I am subscribing to Azure Event Hub using `BackgroundService`.

```
    public class EventConsumerService : BackgroundService
    {
        private const string connectionString = "<event_hub_connection_string>";
        private const string eventHubName = "<event_hub_name>";
        private const string blobStorageConnectionString = "<blob_connection_string>";
        private const string blobContainerName = "<container_name>";

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            string consumerGroup = EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName;

            // Create a blob container client that the event processor will use 
            BlobContainerClient storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobStorageConnectionString, blobContainerName);

            // Create an event processor client to process events in the event hub
            EventProcessorClient processor = new EventProcessorClient(storageClient, consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName);

            // Register handlers for processing events and handling errors
            processor.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessEventHandler;
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorHandler;

            // Start the processing
            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
        }

        static async Task ProcessEventHandler(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // Write the body of the event to the console window
            Console.WriteLine("\tRecevied event: {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.ToArray()));

            await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync(eventArgs.CancellationToken);
        }

        static Task ProcessErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Exception.Message);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

What I see most often is a while loop checking if cancellation is requested but I am not sure where would be the best place to put it because in the `ExecuteAsync` method there is nothing that I would like to be performed on every cycle of the loop.

So basically, I guess that I need to use this to check is cancel is requested:

`while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {}`

just not sure what is the correct way to use it so I don't end up repeating actions unneccessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it to the processor. It will handle cancellation in its own internal code.

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        string consumerGroup = EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName;

        // Create a blob container client that the event processor will use 
        BlobContainerClient storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobStorageConnectionString, blobContainerName);

        // Create an event processor client to process events in the event hub
        EventProcessorClient processor = new EventProcessorClient(storageClient, consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName);

        // Register handlers for processing events and handling errors
        processor.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessEventHandler;
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorHandler;

        // Start the processing
        await processor.StartProcessingAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
```

On a general note, this applies every time you call an `async` function: if possible pass in a `cancellationToken`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to pass it around. Can you give full example so I can accept the answer?